# report in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, report

how do i assign entity or object to report in VS2008.
 I managed to create dataset, that is connected to database, but not to object or entity.

heeelp please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Visual studio 2008 gives me additional menu to standing and it is not in Views as VS2010 but in main menu.

Thanks guys for your help.

Pav

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new Appointment[] {...};
// or
var data = from ... where ... select...;

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "Appointments";
rds.Value = data;

localReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

You can use any `DataTable`, `IEnumerable`, `BindingSource` or `System.Web.UI.IDataSource` as the value of a `ReportDataSource` (the `data` variable in this sample).

The RDL definition looks the same as with database data. Instead of database columns in the dataset definition, there would be object's properties:

```
<DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="Appointments">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="Id">
                <DataField>Id</DataField>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="Name">
                <DataField>Name</DataField>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <Query>
            <DataSourceName>ds</DataSourceName>
            <CommandText>Appointments</CommandText>
        </Query>
    </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

Code Behind:

```
                Dataset dataSet = new Dataset();
                ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
       var emp = new HistoryEntity();     --------------->>> this is my Entity Class
                emp.DateFrom = '2/2/2011';
                emp.DateTo = '2/3/2011';


               //sqlcon/command/Create Select etch...use datadapter and fill to dataSet



               var datasource = new  ReportDataSource("CreatedDataset", dataSet.Tables[0]);
               ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
               ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
               if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
               {
                   WebMessageBox.Show("Sorry,No Records found");
               }
               ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

ASp page:

```
  <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" 
                            Width="1230px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="400px" 
                                  Visible="False">
                                  <LocalReport ReportPath="History.rdlc">
                                  </LocalReport>
                        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I use this in my web app local report(rdlc)

Regards

Comment: yeah i got this thnx,but how do you assign the report to datagrid in report itself? In VS2010 i can assign datasource as object, but i cannot find the same option in VS2008

Comment: What did you mean bind the result of the report to data grid?,Maybe you need to use dataGrid.datasource = dataSet
dataGrid.databind().Does my post help you with your first post(accept as answer). Regards